# How do I acces a variable that is outside my function?

Tags: php, function, variables

I've got a function that requires some variables that are defined outside of my function.
I thought it would be enough to just re-declare my variable in my function with global. But it's not working for some reason.

This is my **code**:

```
$orderNr = $order->get_order_number();

require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF {
    // Page header
    function Header() {
        global $orderNr;

        // Arial bold 9
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);

        // Line break
        $this->Ln(10);
        $this->Multicell(50, 4, $orderNr, 1, 'L');
        $this->Cell(140, 8, '', 1);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on why I'm not able to acces the data of $orderNr inside my function?

Comment: Pass it as parameter, not via the hidden global parameter. That makes your code more specific and is less error prone. Try to remove all global and not use it in the future.

Comment: Declare $orderNr inside your class

Comment: declare the class where the variable comes from and not the variable in your function: `global $order`and `$orderNr = $order->get_order_number();`in class PDF

Answer (score 0):

I do not always get this right quickly, but you should bring both, the order and the PDF library together without coupling it too heave to each other. This will keep things together but flexible:

```
class OrderPdf
{
    public function create(Order $order, $class = 'FPDF') 
    {
       if (is_string($class) {
           $pdf = new $class();
       } else {
           $pdf = $class;
       }

       if (! $pdf instanceof FPDF) {
           throw new InvalidArgumentException(
               sprtinf('Need a FPDF, %s given', var_export($pdf, true)
           );
       }

       $orderNr = $order->get_order_number();

       $this->header($pdf, $orderNr);

       return $pdf;
    }

    function Header(FPDF $pdf, $orderNr)
    {

        // Arial bold 9
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);

        // Line break
        $pdf->Ln(10);
        $pdf->Multicell(50, 4, $orderNr, 1, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(140, 8, '', 1);
    }

    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
require('fpdf.php');

$orderPdf = new OrderPdf();
$pdf = $orderPdf->create($order);
```

The `OrderPdf` object is able to create a FPDF from an order now.